# Нужна ли запятая во фразеологизме "то(,) что доктор прописал"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, фразеология

Это выражение в моей голове звучит цельно, нет смыслового и интонационного акцента на слове "то". Ставить ли в нём запятую?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я считаю, что запятую нужно ставить: **то, что доктор прописал.**
Согласна, что выражение очень похоже на [неразложимые сочетания](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146) ***то что надо*** или ***то что нужно*** (в разговорном значении *очень хороший*).
*У него родители — то что нужно!

Машина для перевозки животных небольшого размера была то что надо.*

Обычные [сложноподчиненные предложения с указательным словом «то»](https://rus.1sept.ru/article.php?ID=200701106):
Отдаете вы последние денежки за то, что доктор прописал. [О. Рамирес. Доктор «Штука» // «Калининградские Новые колеса», 2004.11.26]
*Как говорится, оптимальный вариант для хрупкой женской руки, именно то, что доктор прописал* (Татьяна Устименко. Дочь Господня).
*Мне кажется, для вас это сейчас то, что доктор прописал...* (Ольга Матвеева. Случайные связи)
«То, что доктор прописал»  — название книги (Кристи Голд).